# How to get wsdl work on a web

Tags: soap, wsdl

I am new to wsdl. I have 2 url for 2 wsdl (e.g.htp://something/1?WSDL and htp://something/2?WSDL ) The wsdl contain soap.

I know the 1?WSDL part is working fine on the web site but the problem is I need to call out another element from 2?WSDL...

1?WSDL is user information
2?WSDL is something about the user, all I need to call out from here is the total online time (example)

So after the user login, the page will look like below

```
User name | Registered date | total post count | total online time
y7775     | 11-05-2013      | 368              | 5hrs 36mins
```

Is this doable?
if so then can some one point me a direction?

or should I just put 2 wsdl into 1?

Comment: Need to see some code. So far, this looks like two simple sequential calls - one to first service and one to the second. Then you compose your result object and pass it to the view.

Comment: Thats the problem, I dont have the code with me as this is a question from my friend...he is seeking for some advise regarding the question above. Myself is on php/jquery area...thats why he asked me this question. He thought web guy will know every web languages. Anyway long story short. Is calling the wsdl similar to doing query to the mysql? Can I put it this way - similar to running 2 sql query on the same webpage?

Comment: example: query1 = table1 - Name, Post, query2 = table2 - time. On the result page, it showed Name | Post | time (I know the coding is different, just trying to clearing the logic confusion)